# Media Query is not working for flex-direction

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

new to designing webpages here. I am trying to make the divs in the class from flex-direction: column to flex direction: row when it hits 650px, but it cannot get overwritten with the media query . When I inspected the flex container in the developer tools, the property is strike-through. Any ideas what went wrong here?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhsEY.png)

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-group">

    <div class="stat1">
        <h2>10k+</h2>
        <p>companies</p>
    </div>

    <div class="stat2">
        <h2>314</h2>
        <p>templates</p>
    </div>

    <div class="stat3">
        <h2>12M+</h2>
        <p>queries</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex-group {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 5rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width:600px) {
    .flex-group {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tested your code and works as expected. Maybe you're getting some interference from other styles...

Comment: Yes thanks for the input, it was due to the order of the styles, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue, it was due to the order of the css styles. Previously, I defined the media query before the 'flex-group' class itself. After placing it correctly, the media query is working.

Answer (score 0):

This should apply when the view port is wider than 600px. If you want it to apply when for example the screen is wider than 600px you have to define

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
....
}
```

Maybe that solves the issue.